# What is シ●ブ, and why is it censored？

Tags: words

The other day on the train I saw this advertisement for some tabloid, with headlines all over it, as they do:

[image: シ●ブ愛人]

I'm trying to figure out what `シ●ブ愛人{あいじん}` is. `忍{しのぶ}愛人{あいじん}`? "Sneaky lover"? Assuming `忍{しのぶ}` to be something like the "clandestine" definition used in `忍者{にんじゃ}`, and not the [species of fern](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%8E%E3%83%96). Though, "fern lover" would be kind of interesting.

What is a `シ●ブ愛人`? And why is it censored?

Comment: This is definitely シャブ愛人 (there are lots of Google hits for that that also have "ASKA"), but I have no idea what that means. Notice that the dot is too small to be a full-size kana (plus, it's off-center).

Comment: Apparently [one meaning of シャブ](http://zokugo-dict.com/12si/syabu.htm) is "stimulant", so perhaps this ASKA person was arrested for some sort of drug crime? That might explain the censorship - perhaps シャブ is a particularly vulgar way of referring to drugs or something.

Comment: シャブ is slang for 覚醒剤.

Comment: @senshin Yes... ASKA is a famous singer... he was arrested for using 覚醒剤 with this woman...

Comment: All these comments are helpful, but really they should be answers. Also, still missing is the rationale behind censoring the word.

Comment: @Chocolate, I thought `シャブ` was specifically slang for crystal meth.

Comment: @DaveMG You may be right but I don't really understand the difference, I read [覚醒剤 on Wiki](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A6%9A%E9%86%92%E5%89%A4#.E4.BF.97.E7.A7.B0) but there're so many technical terms... [シャブon俗語辞典](http://zokugo-dict.com/12si/syabu.htm) says シャブ is 覚醒剤 so I think it can also be used as a broad term.

Comment: @Chocolate, Meth is a specific drug, and stimulant (覚醒剤) is a broad category. So, I guess I'm just wondering, if I were writing a story in which a drug addict went to a drug dealer and asked for シャブ, would the reader assume specifically one drug (meth), or not have any specific image in mind?

Comment: @DaveMG Hmm... probably a drug addict and a dealer are both familiar with these names, so they'll confirm it when doing a deal... but I am not familiar with these names/terms at all so if I read シャブ I'd just think it's a kind of 覚醒剤... (麻薬・薬物・覚醒剤とかの専門用語って、私、ホントに無知なんで...すいませ～ん!!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

シャブ is common slang for crystal methamphetamine.

Regular newspapers usually use the more politically-correct 覚醒剤【かくせいざい】, which literally means "stimulant drug", but nearly always refer to methamphetamine or cocaine. This being a tabloid (and perhaps because the term is a little more specific), they went with the stronger word シャブ, but out of that [typical faux-coyness about "loaded" terms in Japanese media](http://www.geocities.co.jp/WallStreet/4845/odio/kinku.html) (*), opted to censor it.

As for the wider context, it's a bit off-topic, but:

Famous 80s artist ASKA was [recently arrested for possession and use of said stimulants](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20140527/k10014750641000.html). The <s>恋人</s> 愛人 part probably refers to the "friend"/"girlfriend" (didn't follow the details too closely) that was charged alongside him (and whose house would have apparently been used to store and consume the narcotics).

*: Apparently, it's really bad if kids get to see a slang term for drug spelt out on a subway ad, but totally fine if they get their fill of half-naked, boob-cupping, barely-legal models on the same ad.

Comment: 「恋人」じゃなくて「愛人」って書いてあるんで、たぶん、ニュアンスとしては「不倫関係」みたいな・・・。（一応、ASKAさん、結婚してはるんで。。。）

Comment: ああ、しまった。やっぱり愛人と書いてった。治してくれてありがとう！

Comment: `Apparently, it's really bad if kids get to see a slang term for drug spelt out on a subway ad, but totally fine if they get their fill of half-naked, boob-cupping, barely-legal models on the same ad.`  This.  And not just for Japan.